# How does React Fragment improve Layout?

Tags: reactjs

This is the Next.js official guide,layout

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

I am looking at one repo,with Layout

```
import { Component, Fragment } from 'react'

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <p>header</p>
            {children}
            <p>footer</p>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

What are the pro and cons of React Fragments?

Comment: If you use `Fragment` no html tag will be rendered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any component must return one Element.
There are three elements:

```
<p>header</p> //1
{children}    //2 +
<p>footer</p> //3
```

So, they would be wrapped by some tag (div, main etc.):

```
<div>
    <p>header</p>
    {children}
    <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

rendered as:

```
 <body>
    <div>
      <p>header</p>
      <p>first paragraph</p>
      <p>second paragraph</p>
      <p>footer</p>
    <div>
 </body>
```

With fragment (you can use `<>` or `<React.Fragment>`):

```
<>
   <p>header</p>
   {children}
   <p>footer</p>
</>
```

rendered as:

```
 <body>
      <p>header</p>
      <p>first paragraph</p>
      <p>second paragraph</p>
      <p>footer</p>
 </body>
```

It is also convenient to use the Fragment in tables when you have one row as component - you will not break the markup.

Under the hood, JSX turns into code like this:

```
"use strict";

const layout = ({
  children
}) => {
  return React.createElement(
             "div", // HTML tag name or React.Fragment
              null, // Props or attributes (for div)
              React.createElement("p", null, "header"), // 1th children of div
              children,                                 // 2nd children of div
              React.createElement("p", null, "footer")  // 3rd children of div
        );
};
```

As you can see `React.createElement()` gets three parameters, first of them is a root `HTML tag` or a `Fragment` instead of which, its content will be put. Unlike `HTML tags`, a `Fragment` can only have a `key` attribute (which is also used only by `React`)

Answer (score -1):

React Fragments, also known as Fragment elements, are a feature introduced in React 16. They are a way to group multiple child elements without introducing an additional wrapper element in the DOM.

Before Fragments, developers often used container elements like  or  to group components, which could lead to unnecessary markup and affect performance. React Fragments offer a cleaner and more efficient solution by encapsulating child elements without affecting the structure of the rendered HTML.

```js
import React from 'react';
const FragmentExample = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my React app.</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default FragmentExample;
```

In the above code snippet, we are using <React.Fragment> to wrap multiple child elements instead of div and any other additional wrapper element.

Here we can also simply use <> … </> as below:

```js
import React from 'react';
const FragmentExample = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
      <p>Welcome to my React app.</p>
    </>
  );
};
export default FragmentExample;
```

React Fragments are a powerful and valuable feature that enhances the development experience in React applications. By mastering the use of Fragments and implementing the seven techniques mentioned, developers can create more efficient, organized, and performant React components, leading to a smoother and more enjoyable user experience.